# Union ruins query

Tags: union, sparql, rdf, geospatial, linked-data

I wrote successfully a query which founds the municipalities and their corresponding bathing waters (the ones that they intersect with) of a given regional unit. Now I would like to do that for two regional units and compare which r. unit has the most. However, the second operand of union fails the [strdf:mbbIntersects()](http://www.strabon.di.uoa.gr/stSPARQL) function.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *
WHERE { 
{
    SELECT (COUNT(?bw) as ?bwCount1) WHERE 
    {
           ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
           ?municipality1 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
           ?municipality1 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

           ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
           ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
           FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
           ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
           FILTER(?concie_0 < 1.5)
    }
}
UNION
{
    SELECT (COUNT(?bw) as ?bwCount2) WHERE 
    {
           ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ"  .
           ?municipality2 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
           ?municipality2 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

           ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
           ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
           FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
           ?bw unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
           FILTER(?concie_0 < 1.5)
    }
}
}
```

Notice that:

1. I am using *the same regional* unit as a *proof* that the data are
   correct.
2. If I comment the 2nd `FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(..`, it will give
   results. Good results with `FILTER(!strdf:mbbIntersects(..` as well.

Result:

> Index: 0, Size: 0

How to fix this?

---

It should be something with the Union, right?

Comment: What SPARQL endpoint/engine are you using?

Comment: I am using endpoint Strabon: http://www.strabon.di.uoa.gr/ @JoshuaTaylor

Comment: Off-topic: I'd suggest you should to learn how to use UNION more efficiently, i.e. only where and when it's necessary. In several posts you used a similar query having two SUB-SELECTs in a UNION. And each time it was suggested first, to move common triple patterns out of it.

Comment: @AKSW I am walking through this, but when nothing works, I return back to the basics, thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the equivalent query is the following (difficult to do this in a comment):

```
SELECT (COUNT(?bw1) as ?bwCount1) (COUNT(?bw2) as ?bwCount2)
WHERE {
  {
    ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
    ?municipality1 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
    ?municipality1 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

    ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
    ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
    FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
    ?bw1 unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
    FILTER(?concie_0 < 1.5)
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
    ?municipality2 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
    ?municipality2 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .

    ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
    ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
    FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
    ?bw2 unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
    FILTER(?concie_0 < 1.5)
  }
}
```

I.e. the two `UNION` clauses are **exactly** the same.  The reason it brings back no data could be that one of the matches doesn't exist, values are being filtered our (e.g., try removing `FILTER(?concie_0 < 1.5)`).  Also try systematically commenting out triple patterns with a `#` at the beginning of the line until you get results, perhaps using `SELECT *` until you have figured out where the lack of a match is occurring.

And the above query can be re-written to focus just on the parts of the `UNION` graph patterns that differ:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?bw1) as ?bwCount1) (COUNT(?bw2) as ?bwCount2)
WHERE {
  ?regional_unit geo:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα "ΠΕΡΙΦΕΡΕΙΑΚΗ ΕΝΟΤΗΤΑ ΗΡΑΚΛΕΙΟΥ" .
  ?bw geos:hasGeometry ?bw_geo .
  ?bw_geo geos:asWKT ?bw_geo_wkt .
  {
    ?municipality1 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
    ?municipality1 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .
    ?bw1 unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
    FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
  }
  UNION
  {
    ?municipality2 geo:ανήκει_σε ?regional_unit .
    ?municipality2 geo:έχει_γεωμετρία ?geometry .
    ?bw2 unt:has_concie_0 ?concie_0 .
    FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt)) .
  }
  FILTER(?concie_0 < 1.5)
}
```

Comment: Note that OP explicitly mentioned in the question that the two sides are the same: "I am using the same regional unit as a proof that the data are correct."

Comment: Scott, @JoshuaTaylor is right, I will have two regional units, I am just using the same here to prove that there is no error in the dataset! Maybe my question is unclear, but I am trying to update it and it seems fine to me! **I am pretty sure** that the 2nd SELECT *fails* here:`FILTER(strdf:mbbIntersects(?geometry, ?bw_geo_wkt))` .

Comment: My main point is that there is absolutely no need for sub-selects. I'm not clear why running the same query twice could possibly lead to different results.  Chances are that the problem is with `strdf:mbbIntersects()`.  Also check that `?geometry` and `?bw_geo_wkt` have the same result, but I can't imagine them being different without some error in the SPARQL engine.

Comment: @scotthenninger, because in the first query, we could search for USA and in the second for Russia. But that didn't work, so I thought that Russia (the 2nd query) may had a problem in the dataset, thus I used USA in both queries, **which I know that works** well. The problem arises when I ask the (almost) same query again..The 2nd query fails in the `strdf:mbbIntersects()`. Do you get my point now? :)

Comment: And all works when you take out `strdf:mbbIntersects()`, correct?  Yea, I do get it.  There is likely a bug in `strdf:mbbIntersects()` that won't allow it to be used in the same query (thread issue maybe?).  You may need to run the queries separately and calculate the union programatically.